# Facebook "Not Logged In" error before actual login

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using latest Facebook SDK 3.1.1.
I am calling method  `[[FBSession activeSession] openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {...}`

I am expecting (and it actually appears on my device) typical web view login dialog with e-mail and password fields. But on another device it shows error message: "Not logged in. You are not logged in. Please, login and try again". And this is very strange, because I am actually asking for login.
Has anybody faced that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an official Facebook bug that happened after the February 6 breaking changes. More info here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/331103197009388?browse=search_51154c83b3ffe0750572464

Answer (score 1):

It can mean that you forgot to add the Platform (for example the Android Platform) to your Facebook developer account online. Go to Settings -> Basic -> Add Platform.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have been hit with the recent FB outage:

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2027627/facebook-redirection-bug-is-now-fixed-but-troubling.html